# Raspi Camera not detected

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, detection, raspberry-pi4, firmware

My camera is not being detected by my raspi. When running:

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

in the terminal it outputs:

```
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

I am pretty confident it is plugged in correctly. I accidently plugged it into the "display" ribbon cable connector on the raspi and the camera lights up to show it is getting power but when I plug it into the correct "camera" ribbon connector that same light does not appear.

When I run "sudo raspi-config" and go into interfacing options there is no "camera" option only the "Legacy Camera". Even when enabling the legacy camera it still does not detect.

The camera I purchased is the "Freenove Camera Module for RPi (8MP)"

I think I have tried getting all the updates I need such as running "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" as well as installing the packages "pip3 install picamera" but nothing seems to work.

Here is some test code:

```
import picamera

class CameraTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.camera = picamera.PiCamera()

    def capture_image(self, filename):
        self.camera.capture(filename)

    def close(self):
        self.camera.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        camera_test = CameraTest()
        camera_test.capture_image("test_image.jpg")
        print("Image captured successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
    finally:
        camera_test.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
An error occurred: Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi- 
config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ben6brewer/Desktop/Greenhouse/CamTest.py", line 21, in
camera_test.close()
NameError: name 'camera_test' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

I get supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0 too on Pi Zero 2 W, but the camera works fine with libcamera-still -o test.jpg. It can capture image and video. So try libcamera-still -o test.jpg and see if the camera is already working.